# C# Error reading domains in different domain

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I have this code that works just fine when logged onto a domain:

```
DirectoryContext context = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.DirectoryServer, serverIP, username, password);            

var forest1 = Forest.GetForest(context);

using (var forest = Forest.GetForest(context))
{
    foreach (Domain domain in forest.Domains)
    {
        DirectoryEntry deDomain = domain.GetDirectoryEntry();
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", domain.Name, deDomain.Path, deDomain.Guid));
    }
}
```

And it also works fine when accessing a domain that I am not logged onto ie. the connection goes through ok and forest.Domains is populated.

The problem I have is that whenever I try to access any property of the domain object (eg. domain.DomainMode) I get 'Unknown error (0x80005000)' - any ideas?

Comment: LIkely to be permissions if you are not logged into the domain. I would assume that certain information is available, but not detailed information without authorization.

Comment: Permission is the obvious culprit but I am not sure. If I get the DirectoryEntry directly using the guid or similar then I can read all the domains properties just fine - It is only when iterating as above that I get the error.